# Refresh an element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a anchor element on a page that i need to refresh every 5 seconds. It is only one anchor so i do not need a cycle plugin here.

How can I refresh the element i want without reloading the page. Any plugins?

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"? Do you want to regenerate it every 5 seconds?

Comment: the effect should be like someone has refreshed the page..reload the contents

Comment: If one say `Refresh`, what comes first on my mind is the browser. What do you mean by refresh an element? can you give example of what do you want to happen in the end?

Comment: Assuming he's really talking about reloading the page, then the solution would be to use `.load()` , then extract the same element to replace it. However that would be incredibly stupid, as using ajax to load only the data that need to be changed would be much lighter and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than going for any plug in Make use of **setInterval()** function for this kind of repeat function :

```
setInterval ( "doSomething()", 5000 );

function doSomething ( )
{
  // (do something here)
}
```

More : [setInterval()](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)

Comment: this still not answer the question `Refresh an element in jquery`. Who knows, the OP might already know `setInterval` and just don't know how to use it in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ajax functionality in jQuery : [Documentation link!](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Especialy the .load() method will help.

Please note that this will only work for files located on the same server (a security measure in javaScript). I you want to pull from a remote server, you'll need a server side proxy to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myIntervalId = setInterval("function_to_execute()", 5000);
```

This `function_to_execute()` will be called every 5 seconds after your page loads. You can put your refreshing code there and it will be executed every 5 seconds.

It does not refresh your page unless you explicitly refresh it inside the `function_to_execute()` function.

To cancel this timer, call -

```
clearInterval ( myIntervalId );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval ( "UpdateDivID()", 5000 );

function UpdateDivID()
{

$('#AnchorID').html('Someone has refreshed the page');

}
```

Will change the html of the AnchorID.. Be more specific.